# Java JMenuItem in loop

Tags: java, swing

I want to add menu items lines each for the list of colours, but have the error like

> "at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown
>   Source)"

in my loop adding JMenuItem:

```
String[] colors = {
        "Blue", 
        "Yellow",
        "Orange",
        "Red", 
        "White", 
        "Black", 
        "Green", 
};

JMenuItem menuItem;
JMenu mnBackground = new JMenu("Background");
for (int mi=0; mi<=colors.length; mi++){
    String pos = colors[mi];
    JMenuItem Jmi =new JMenuItem(pos); // ERROR, though manually added Strings works...
    mnBackground.add(Jmi);
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Add full stack trace please.

Comment: Remember: Arrays are zero based in Java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The loop for should be:

```
for (int mi = 0; mi < colors.length; mi++)
```

not

```
for (int mi = 0; mi <= colors.length; mi++)
```